# HandleError doesn't redirect to specified view? Conflict to Elmah.MVC?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5, elmah

I had the following action and **Elmah.MVC** is installed.

```
// POST: /Venue/Delete/5
[HttpPost, ActionName("Delete"), HandleError(ExceptionType = typeof(SqlException), View = "DbError")]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public async Task<ActionResult> DeleteConfirmed(int id)
{
```

And I tried to raise an error by deleting a FK referred row and the following page is shown in the elmah page. However, it still redirected to the default standard error page. (Which has the hard coded error message of

> Error.
>
> An error occurred while processing your request.

The `DbError.cshtml` has the following content.

```
@model System.Web.Mvc.HandleErrorInfo

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Error";
}

<h1 class="text-danger">Error.</h1>
<h2 class="text-danger">@Model.Exception</h2>
```

I expected the detail description of the `SqlException` been shown up.

```
System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException
The DELETE statement conflicted with the REFERENCE constraint "FK_dbo.......
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you modified the web.config ?

```
<system.web>
  <customErrors mode="On" defaultRedirect="Error" />
</system.web>
```

Comment: Yes, I tried it on my local VS development machine after updating the web.config file. It still just show `Error.
An error occurred while processing your request.`, which is the default error page instead of `DbError`.